# How to add operators in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How i can use operators like `$max` `$min` with mongoose

I tried

```
 User.find({Followers:max});
```

but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .aggregate() method

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "max": { "$max": "$Followers" }, 
        "min": { "$min": "$Followers" } 
    }}
])
```

The _id should be null otherwise the query will only return max/min for each group

Answer (score 0):

$max and $min operators will not work with .find(),
you need to use .aggregate() for it to work.

```
    user.aggregate([ 
          { "$group": { 
                "_id": null,
                "maxfollowers": { "$max": "$Followers" }, 
                "minfollowers": { "$min": "$Followers" } 
          }}
       ])
```

_id field is mandatory in the $group and to find the max/min values for Followers for the entire collection not for special group it needs to be set to null otherwise if you want the result for each group you can use that field name instead of null e.g.

```
    user.aggregate([ 
      { "$group": { 
             "_id": "$name",
             "maxfollowers": { "$max": "$Followers" }, 
             "minfollowers": { "$min": "$Followers" } 
          }}
     ])
```